# Black window with Qt Quick (5.6.2) on MacOSX 10.14

Tags: macos, qt, qml, qt5

This simple application:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window
{
  visible: true
  width: 640
  height: 480
  title: qsTr("TEST BUG COLOR QT 5.6")
  color: "red"
}
```

Gives this result on Windows:
[image]

But gives this result on Mac OSX 10.14:
[image]

What's wrong?

Please note that I am not using the new dark mode.

UPDATE: it seems it is related to https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-71206

Comment: Did you try with Qt 5.9.7 (or more recent) ?

Comment: @BenjaminT: good idea. So I tried. It doesn't work for 5.9.7. But it does work for 5.10.1, 5.11.3 and 5.12.0. The problem is, I cannot update for now...

Comment: Having read the comments in the Qt bug report, it seems your issue is caused by an incompatibility between your versions of Qt and xcode toolchain. So either you upgrade your Qt version or downgrade your xcode version. See this post on Qt blog: https://blog.qt.io/blog/2018/11/08/qt-macos-10-14-mojave/